# Unable to run Apache Drill windows 7

Tags: windows, apache-drill

I'm trying to run Apache Drill on Windows 7, I have the requirements provided in the documentation and yet when I run it in terminal I get this error :

```
Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins/dfs.sys.drill" (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins/dfs.sys.drill"
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:109)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:66)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:78)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:734)
at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:519)
at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:587)
at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:366)
at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:259)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins/dfs.sys.drill"
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore.get(FilePStore.java:140)
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore$Iter$DeferredEntry.getValue(FilePStore.java:219)
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry.createPlugins(StoragePluginRegistry.java:168)
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry.init(StoragePluginRegistry.java:132)
at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:244)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:100)
... 18 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
at [Source: [B@6c8d3583; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:1351)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1252)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912)
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.serialize.JacksonSerializer.deserialize(JacksonSerializer.java:44)
at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.local.FilePStore.get(FilePStore.java:138)
... 23 more
```

when I go to tmp folder I find only one file

Does anyone know how to fix this ? 
Thank you

Comment: Did you find `/drill/sys.storage_plugins` directory in `tmp` folder?

Comment: What is your drill version? Check this drill [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-2158).

Comment: @devツ sorry for my late reply, /drill/sys.storage_plugins is created in tmp folder but it doesn't contain all necessary files ( I compared it with the number of files I get when I install Drill on an other computer), I even tried copying the folder created in the computer that works into the tmp folder but then when I restart the drill it gives me a different error "unable to run program .."

Comment: I was getting a FileNotFoundException for `/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins` when running `sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local" from a mapped network share.  Moving the `apache-drill-1.9.0` directory to my C: drive fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, 
It worked when I replaced the /tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins with the files created in the same location from an other computer, I still don't know why this one can't create all of them but at least now it works !

Answer (score 2):

delete/move the folder `/tmp/drill/sys.storage_plugins` & restart the drill. It'll create the folder while starting the drill & now find the issue by comparing old & new.
It worked for me.

Comment: when I do that, an other error occurs saying " cannot run program... Create process failed "

Comment: I'm able to start drill using this. not sure why its happening with you. it'll automatically create default data storage plugins on the initialization of drill

Comment: It can't create files in tmp folder because it's a 32 bits Windows and Drill only supports 64 bits, that's why it worked with you and with my other computer ... I just skipped that line in the documentation of Apache Drill and only figured it out recently, thank you for your help though

Answer (score -2):

It's 2018 03 02, and this error is STILL appearing for people (like me) trying to install & run Apache Drill in Embedded Mode on Windows 10...

HERE'S WHAT WORKED FOR ME:  INSTALL Drill only to

> C:\apache-drill-1.12.0*

NOTE that this creates a

> C:\tmp\sys.storage_plugins\ directory RATHER than DELETE this directory, I simply MOVED this directory temporarily to my laptop's desktop;

THEN I restarted the Drill Shell as follows...

LAUNCH a common Windows 10 cmd console

> cd to C:\apache-drill-1.12.0\bin\ EXECUTE this command: 
>   sqlline sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local;schema=dfs"

RESULT:  I get the following (WONDERFUL) initialization output:

DRILL_ARGS - " sqlline.bat -u jdbc:drill:zk=local;schema=dfs" Calculating HADOOP_CLASSPATH ... HBASE_HOME not detected... Calculating Drill classpath... Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
-Xms512M Mar 02, 2018 8:36:33 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.8 2014-04-29 01:25:26... Property "url" is required apache drill 1.12.0 "what ever the mind of man can conceive and believe, drill can query"

> 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local>

FROM here I issued the "SHOW DATABASES;" command... and it WORKED !

> 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SHOW DATABASES;
>   +---------------------+ |     SCHEMA_NAME     |
>   +---------------------+ | INFORMATION_SCHEMA  | | cp.default          | | dfs.default         | | dfs.root            | | dfs.tmp            | | sys                 |
>   +---------------------+ 6 rows selected (5.797 seconds)
>   0: jdbc:drill:zk=local>